# How to automatically repeat formulas when a new row is added in google sheets? Arrayforumla or script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been researching to find a solution for this but it seems I'll need some help. I'm trying to set up some formulas on a google sheet so when my VA adds a new row of information, my formulas will automatically populate the new rows.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xapTzLPzi0v2ZMnOcOn81VF3MSGaV_j0bFuxIsdHNs4/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the spreadsheet of how it is now. I don't want my VA touching the grey columns because those have the formulas. But, they need to copy the formula every time they add a new row. The spreadsheet currently has the formulas that need to be manually copied.

I've tried the arrayforumla but I can't seem to get it to populate the rows with the correct number. It formulates row 2 and then repeats for every row. This was the arrayformula for Column B I had made and placed in the header:

={"10%+";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K2:K="",,SUM(K2*(1+10%))))}

I've looked into app scripts but the code is confusing and when I implement a script I found on here, it doesn't work.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can give me some guidance on what I'm doing here. Columns/formulas I want to automatically fill in are: B, C, G, H, I, K.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the formulas you can use:

```
B: =A2*(1+10%) >> ={"10%+"; arrayformula(A2:A*(1+10%))}
C: =A2*(1-10%) >> ={"10%-"; arrayformula(A2:A*(1-10%))}
G: =F2+1       >> ={"Total Competitive Sellers"; arrayformula(F2:F+1)}
H: =D2/G2      >> ={"Sales Equity (Units/Mo)"; arrayformula(D2:D/G2:G)}
I: =E2/G2      >> ={"Sales Equity (Revenue/Mo)"; arrayformula(E2:E/G2:G)}
K: =H2*J2      >> ={"Estimated Net/Mo"; arrayformula(H2:H*J2:J)}
```

These account for headers, so you can place them in the first row. They will autofill down the column.

---

You could also wrap the calculations in `IF` statements so that rows without a data entry stay blank:

```
B: =A2*(1+10%) >> ={"10%+"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", A2:A*(1+10%)))}
C: =A2*(1-10%) >> ={"10%-"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", A2:A*(1-10%)))}
G: =F2+1       >> ={"Total Competitive Sellers"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", F2:F+1))}
H: =D2/G2      >> ={"Sales Equity (Units/Mo)"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", D2:D/G2:G))}
I: =E2/G2      >> ={"Sales Equity (Revenue/Mo)"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", E2:E/G2:G))}
K: =H2*J2      >> ={"Estimated Net/Mo"; arrayformula(if(A2:A="", "", H2:H*J2:J))}
```